# What's the syntax to open a Tracker window from the command line in Haiku?

Tags: command-line, window, bash-scripting, haiku

I've tried these:

```
Tracker /path
Tracker /path/
/path
/path/
```

...but no dice (the former two open Tracker's preferences window and the latter complain that /path is a directory.)  What should I do?  Is there some `hey` command I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some help from [Scot Hacker](http://www.birdhouse.org/beos/bible/bos/ch_scripting6.html):

```
hey Tracker load "file(/path/)"
```